# How do I revert a hg rollback?

Tags: version-control, mercurial

This may sound silly but when I wanted to revert a hg merge command, I issued "hg rollback".

Later i realized I have to use "hg update -C -r ." to clear the merged but uncommitted changes.

Now I want my last commit back. Is this possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe. The opposite of `hg rollback` is `hg commit`. If you didn't add/remove any files with `hg add`/`remove`/`addremove`, running `hg commit` once more should give you the state before the rollback.

But you're in the middle of a merge and `hg commit` doesn't support `--dryRun`, so I'm wary what would happen in this case. You will probably get an error but I'm **not sure**

To try this, just make a copy of the workspace somewhere else (i.e. copy the parent folder which contains the `.hg` folder). This is your whole project. You can try to fix the mess in the copy. If something breaks, you can always delete the copy and try something else.

Alternatively, you can clone the project using `hg clone`. If the project already includes messed up changesets, then you can exclude them with `-r`.